# Generate formulas on sheet2 to display non-empty row data from sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I copy data from SQL and paste it into sheet1. The amount of rows changes each time we get the data.

I need to display info from particular columns of sheet1 on sheet2.

Starting at row 2, Sheet2 should look like this:

```
    Column A =VALUE('Sheet1'!AK2)
    Column B =VALUE('Sheet1'!G2)
    Column C =VALUE('Sheet1'!F2)
    Column D =VALUE('Sheet1'!Q2)
    Column E =VALUE('Sheet1'!R2)
    Column F =VALUE('Sheet1'!S2)
    Column G =VALUE('Sheet1'!T2)
    Column H =VALUE('Sheet1'!U2)
```

With each row increasing (AK3, AK4 etc.) until all rows from sheet1 are displayed. I can't have it display empty rows at the end. This is why I need VBA to enter the formulas for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro10()
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long

    arr = Array(37, 7, 6, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        For i = 1 To 8
            lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, arr(i - 1)).End(xlUp).Row
            lr = application.max(lr, 2)
            .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lr, i)).Formula = _
                "=value(" & Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, arr(i - 1)).Address(0, 0, external:=True) & ")"
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting : Run-Time error '9' - Subscript out of range - .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Formula = _
                "=value(" & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(2, arr(i + 1)).Address(0, 0, external:=True) & ")"

Comment: it also starts to fill in on row one instead of row 2

Comment: Man I really appreciate your help, I have another error now on this line: lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: is `lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, arr(i - 1)).End(xlUp).Row` not supposed to be `lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells( Worksheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, arr(i - 1)).End(xlUp).Row` ? - The `.Cells` has `Sheet1` ref but the `.Rows.Count` is going to `Sheet2` cos of the `With`

Comment: @jamheadart - If Sheet1 and Sheet2 are in the same workbook, they will have the same .Rows.Count. Yes, it's being read from Sheet2, not Sheet1 but it doesn't matter. Sheet1 would have to be in an external XLS workbook while Sheet2 is an XLSX workbook to make a difference.

Comment: Jeeped, not sure what the issue is, but it is still erroring out on that line even after I updated it to you new edit.

Comment: Ahh you learn something new every day - I always thought the .Rows.Count was sheet-specific, since you specify the column - now I see that the address is just Range-specific but that Range is defined by the .Cells object! Cool!

Comment: @Jeeped - Well that seems to work mostly, however there is something odd happening, for Column E it starts filling in on row 1 (everything else starts on row 2) and then stops on row 2) Otherwise it works

Comment: Then there is nothing in Sheet1!R:R (18th column). I can add a safety for the second row though.

Comment: Looks like I still have an issue. Let me try this, if there is data in AK copy all the requested cells for that row no mater what, as some cells could be randomly blank. so even if the other cells are blank copy the data. - Can this be done?

Comment: There is also another issue. When I run it more than once it changes 2 of the columns to text type and then the fields get messed up. I have found a solution to both of the issues I listed. Since column 37 will always contain data, I had the formula look at that to determine where the last row is. And then added code to  set each cell to type to general. this fixed my issue. Thanks @Jeeped for your help.

Comment: Here is what I changed on the first lr line "lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, 37).End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: and just after the second lr I added a line with: .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lr, i)).NumberFormat = "General"

Comment: @jeeped, I am going to mark your answer as the correct one now, if you could go and update the code to reflect the changes for others. thanks. :)